# Listview dividers color with HoloEveryWhere

Tags: android, listview, divider, holoeverywhere

I'm using HoloEveryWhere to get support of the Holo themes on android 2.x and I want to change the default color of my ListView dividers.

I did this :

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listRecherche"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#e5e5e5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

It works well on android 4.x but in 2.x, what I get is no more dividers and instead a #e5e5e5 background on the whole ListView.

I've thought about a height problem since I know that changing the dividers color resets the dividers height. This is why I've set heights at the end... but no effect.

Comment: Use a drawable instead of an RGB color Just  put a file named divider.xml in res/drawable/ so you can access it as R.drawable.divider; if you can access it that way, then you can use android:divider="@drawable/divider" in the XML for ListView.    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#ffcdcdcd" android:endColor="#ffcdcdcd" android:angle="270.0" /> And in styles.xml for listview item    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>

Comment: Yes. This is a workaround but it is making it. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a drawable instead of an RGB color Just put a file named divider.xml in res/drawable/ so you can access it as R.drawable.divider; if you can access it that way, then you can use android:divider="@drawable/divider" in the XML for ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <shape xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <gradient 
       android:startColor="#ffcdcdcd" 
       android:endColor="#ffcdcdcd" 
       android:angle="270.0" />
```

And in styles.xml for listview item

```
<item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item> 
<item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with a gradient shape, but i did manage to make this trick work with a rectangle solid shape

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/your_color_here" />
</shape>`